# Flexbox align content in flexed item

Tags: html, css

How can I align content in a flexed item?
The title to the top and the "rest"-content centred?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1wc5kv0d/4/

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.fixed-width-height {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inline-wrapper>span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h3>
            title
        </h3>
        <div class="should-center">
            <span>Lorem Ispum</span>
            <span>Icon</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>
            another title
        </h3>
        <div class="should-center">
            <div class="inline-wrapper">
                <div class="fixed-width-height">
                    <span>Name</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that the titles (h3's) **stay on top** and the content **below should be equally centred**. (Lorem Ipsum should be on the same height as "Name")

Is state:
[image]

Should be (Forget that black stroke, photoshop struggled):

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a visual desired output?

Comment: Yeah sure. Added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.should-center` and `.col` arn't flex items.

If you'd make the `.should-center` `display: flex`, you can use `flex-grow: 1` to let it grow to `100%`, then use `align-items: center;` to vertically align them.

I've also added `display: flex;` to the `.col` to ensure all the childs are able to grow the the parent

```
.col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.should-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col{
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.should-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
}

.fixed-width-height{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inline-wrapper > span{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h3{
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h3>
     title
    </h3>
    <div class="should-center">
      <span>Lorem Ispum</span>
      <span>Icon</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h3>
    another title
    </h3>
    <div class="should-center">
    <div class="inline-wrapper">
        <div class="fixed-width-height">
        
        </div>
        <span>Name</span>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah nice. Thank you. On the .col class `flex-direction: column;` has to be applied too.

Comment: Yea, I did add that to the CSS itself, thought it didn't need to be stated separated. I've accepted your edit, it makes more sense! Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
.inline-wrapper > span{
  vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;


}
h3{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: I do not want space around. I need the content below h3 to be centred on the same height. See the "is" and "should" state in the starter post